# Contempt contemptible contemptuous -?

Tags: meaning

Having trouble knowing how to use contempt, contemptible and contemptuous.
I have an idea contempt is like when you don't like someone or if you are rude in a court but can you please explain in an easy way.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Contempt" is a noun ( https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/contempt ):

"Contemptuous" is an adjective ( https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/contemptuous )

"Contemptible" is also an adjective ( https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/contemptible ) but describes the object of scorn

So - contempt is what you feel, contemptuous is how you express it and contemptible describes the object of your contempt.

Comment: Ok I get it now, ta.